# Why can't I use the result of $.getJSON() immediately?

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I am trying to get my $.getJSON to work but it returns nothing. Here is my jQuery:

```
$('#courseSelect').bind('change', function()
{
    data = $.getJSON('lessons.js');
    var html ='<select name="lessonSelect id="lessonSelect">';
    var len = data.length;
    alert(data.length); //this alerts "undefined"
    for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
        html += '<option value="' + data[i].value + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>';
    }
    html +='</select>';
    alert(html); //this alerts <select...></select> 
    //but no option tags because there's nothing to loop through
    $('lessonsDiv').html(html);
});
```

This is my lessons.js file

```
   {"lessons": 
     [
          {"value": "1", "name": "Lesson 1"},
          {"value": "2", "name": "Lesson 2"},
          {"value": "3", "name": "Three"}
     ]
    }
```

Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is create a new select list of lessons when a course first is selected. But for now, I'm just trying to get this getJSON method to work but it's not. Be great if anyone can see what's wrong with. Is it expecting a different sort of data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The call to [`getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON) is asynchonrous; the result is not available immediately. What is returned from `getJSON()` is the [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object which is monitoring the state of the asynchoronous request.

You need to register a callback (which is what the second parameter is for), which is executed *after* the response is available. The `jqXHR` object which is handling the asynchronous request will execute your callback automatically once the request has completed successfully.

```
$('#courseSelect').bind('change', function() {
    $.getJSON('lessons.js', function(data) {
        var html = '<select name="lessonSelect id="lessonSelect">';
        var len = data.length;
        alert(data.length); //this alerts "undefined"
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            html += '<option value="' + data[i].value + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>';
        }
        html += '</select>';
        alert(html); //this alerts <select...></select> 
        //but no option tags because there's nothing to loop through
        $('lessonsDiv').html(html);
    });
});​
```

Once you've done this, `data` would be an object such as;

```
var data = {"lessons": 
 [
      {"value": "1", "name": "Lesson 1"},
      {"value": "2", "name": "Lesson 2"},
      {"value": "3", "name": "Three"}
 ]
};
```

So you'd actually need to use `data.lessons` to access the array you've got (and `data.lessons.length` to retrieve the length of it).

Comment: pass the `data` object in your anonymous function? :/ or am i just being retarded.

Comment: @f0x not necessarily you have to pass `data` if its not defined the second argument is treated as the callback

Comment: @3nigma: f0x was correcting my omission of the `data` parameter from the callback, not on the `data` you can optionally pass to `getJSON`

Comment: That's what I was doing before and it's ultimately what I'm trying to achieve but I'm trying to make sure that $.getJSON() actually returns something first (taking it step by step) but it doesn't..

Anyway, I reverted back to what you've done here which was what I was doing before but it still alerts undefined

Comment: @user1219572: See my update. You should be using `data.lessons` rather than `data` to access the array (but you still need to do all this in the callback).

Comment: @user1219572: You need to read the answer again since you doesn't seem to understand the differences between sync/async. Also update your question with the current code.

Comment: Hey, I'm accessing it via data.lessons an data.lessons.length and it works! Now I can move onto my next step!!!

Answer (score 3):

Your following code:

```
data = $.getJSON('lessons.js')
```

doesn't work. AJAX is not synchronous. It is, [as its name says](https://www.google.fr/?q=what%20does%20ajax%20mean), *asynchronous*. Which means that you don't wait till the answer comes back. You specify a callback function which will handle the datas received.

For example:

```
$.getJSON('lessons.js', handleDatas)
// This function will be executed when the datas come back
function handleDatas(data) {
    // use the `data` variable here
}
```

Although it is usually used that way:

```
$.getJSON('lessons.js', function(data) {
    // use the `data` variable here
}
```

There, we use an *anonymous function* as a callback.

For more information, take a look at the examples on the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).